# What's the best way to transfer bitcoins between two exchanges?

Tags: exchanges

I'd like to transfer bitcoins in my Kraken account to my Poloniex account. What would be the best (a.k.a. cheapest) way to do that?

Comment: Kraken BTC -> ETH -> Poloniex ETH -> BTC
That's the fastest and cheap way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Withdraw your Bitcoins from your Kraken account directly to an address provided by your Poloniex account.

Comment: Can the same be done from coinbase to kraken?

Comment: Yes it can. Any exchanges that provide a deposit address.

Comment: Do you know why one of the comments suggested converting to ETH is/was superior? Do you know how much processing time your suggestion takes, is it instant transfer?

Comment: At the moment that would cost 6 USD!

Comment: Based on readings, one should be careful transfering ETH between exchanges as some exchanges seem to send the money as smart contracts and other exchanges seem not to be able to receive from contracts, only wallet addresses.   I *believe* I first read this in context of Cryptopia but seems it is not an uncommon issue amongst numerous exchanges.
Advice was to thoroughly verify first or just don't move from exchg to exchg.  Move from exch to a personal wallet and then wallet to an exchange instead.